# Li-Ion charger using LM338 & LM358

Tags: circuit-design, battery-charging, comparator

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/18650-2600mah-battery-datasheet-and-working/?unapproved=88488&moderation-hash=25b3e2c68773281c56bca826da89ca24#comment-88488) on building a basic Li-Ion charger for a single cell.
I have the output from the LM338 set to 4.2 volts as described in the tutorial but dont seem to be able to get the led to light with the battery not connected or with the battery connected and full.
The opamp output voltage never seems to change from low to high.

I have removed the 3V3 zenner diode from my circuit as I was advised to do this.
The only other difference between my circuit and  the one in the tutorial link is I'm using a LM358 opamp as opposed to the 714 opamp.

Would using the LM358 make that much difference or is the circuit design unfeasible anyway?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faa0m8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: To avoid a fire and explosion, use a battery charger IC made to do the job properly.

Comment: Have you read the datasheets of both op-amps to find differences when used like this? Or used a simulator to see what happens with both op-amps? Or asked the person who designed the circuit? That circuit uses the op-amp as comparator. Besides it does not even measure the cell voltage directly but via a diode. Are you sure you want to charge lithium batteries with a makeshift circuit found on an unknown website that you can't trust, as the circuit can explode the batteries and burn down a house if incorrectly designed and built? Why not simply use a dedicated all-in-one charger chip?